# Sequence in an Unbounded Subset of a Metric Space

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

Suppose we have a metric space $(X, d)$ and an unbounded subset $S \subset X$. Let $s_{0} \in X$. How do you show that there is a sequence $s_{n}$ in $S$ so that $d(s_{n}, s_{0}) > n, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just construct it recursively one point at a time. $S$ is unbounded, so there is a point $s_1\in S$ such that $d(s_1,s_0)>1$. For the same reason there is a point $s_2\in S$ such that $d(s_2,s_0)>2$. And so on.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand how you can construct it recursively. How can you guarantee there is a point $s_{1} \in S$ such that $d(s_{1}, s_{0}) > 1$?

Comment: @JohnDavid: That’s an immediate consequence of the fact that $S$ is unbounded. If there were no such point, then $S$ would be a subset of $\{x\in X:d(x,s_0)\le 1\}$, a bounded set.

Answer (score 0):

A subset $S$ of a metric space $M$ is bounded if there exists a radius $r>0$ such that $S$ is contained in the $r-\text{neighborhood}$ $M_{r}p$ for some $p \in M$. If $S$ is unbounded, then for all neighborhoods $M_n (s_0)$ there is a point $s_n \in S$ such that $s_n \not\in M_n (s_0)$. Then it follows from the definition of $M_n (s_0)$ that $d(s_0, s_n) > n$.